# Why does my string print in the wrong place?

Tags: c++, output, operator-overloading

I'm expected this output:

> Addition: 5/6/92+5/6/92=10/12/184

but I get this output:

> 5/6/92+5/6/92=Addition: 10/12/184

Why is this happening?

How can I solve this without modifying the main function?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date {
    int mo, da, yr;
    public:
        Date(int m, int d, int y) {
            mo = m;
            da = d;
            yr = y;
        }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os,
        const Date & dt);
    Date operator + (const Date & dat) const {
        Date newDate(0, 0, 0);
        newDate.mo = dat.mo + mo;
        newDate.da = dat.da + da;
        newDate.yr = dat.yr + yr;
        cout << dat << "+" << mo << "/" << da << "/" << yr << "=";
        return newDate;
    }
};

ostream & operator << (ostream & os,
    const Date & dt) {
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    cout << "Addition: " << dt + dt;
}
```

Comment: The compiler assumes that it can reorder the `+` operator with the `<<` operator since they are independent.

Comment: This is for my college homework. That's what my problem demands. I would never write something like this.

Comment: @stark they are not independent. The + operator executes first. If it would happen the other way around you would be adding a ostream to a Date and that's not possible

Comment: I recommend grabbing a debugger and simply stepping through your code. That's how you can gain insight in these things

Comment: @Jupiter: No, stark is right. There is no ordering constraint between `os << "Addition:"` relative to `dt + dt`.

Comment: This is really tricky, if you really can't modify main. It can be done, but the answer is insane and bad code.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7290807b97d7cd07

Comment: @MooingDuck you have my eternal gratitude. I would give you a beer if I could.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dt + dt` is being evaluated before the `cout << "Addition: "` is executed.

`std::ostream`  does not have 1-parameter member `operator<<` methods that take a `const char[]` or a `Date` as input, so it has to call 2-parameter non-member `operator<<` overloads instead.  So the statement `cout << "Addition: " << dt + dt;` ends up looking more like this to the compiler:

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Addition: "), dt + dt);
```

In the outer `operator<<` call, your compiler is choosing to evaluate the 2nd parameter (`dt + dt`) before evaluating the 1st parameter (`operator<<(cout, "Addition: ")`).

You can't really get the result you want without modifying your `main()` to change the order of evaluations to force the order you want, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date {
    int mo, da, yr;

    public:
        Date(int m, int d, int y) {
            mo = m;
            da = d;
            yr = y;
        }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Date & dt) {
        os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
        return os;
        }

    Date operator + (const Date & dat) const {
        Date newDate(dat.mo + mo, dat.da + da, dat.yr + yr);
        cout << *this << "+" << dat << "=";
        return newDate;
    }
};

int main() {
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    cout << "Addition: ";
    cout << dt + dt;
}
```

Though, it would generally be better to remove the output printing from your `operator+` altogether, just let `main()` print out want it wants:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date {
    int mo, da, yr;

    public:
        Date(int m, int d, int y) {
            mo = m;
            da = d;
            yr = y;
        }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Date & dt) {
        os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
        return os;
        }

    Date operator + (const Date & dat) const {
        return Date(dat.mo + mo, dat.da + da, dat.yr + yr);
    }
};

int main() {
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    Date sum = dt + dt;
    cout << "Addition: " << dt << "+" << dt << "=" << sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at `cout << "Addition: " << dt + dt;`.

What's happening is, `dt + dt` is being evaluated FIRST, which contains a `cout` inside the evaluation. After that, the program prints `"Addition: "` and finally the result of the previous evaluation.

Do you see the issue here? It's not reading from left to right as a human would, and evaluating when it sees the `+` operator. It's evaluating everything that needs to be processed (and calling the `cout` that's inside the `+`), then once it has all the answers it goes to print from left to right.

Having a print statement inside operators is generally not a good idea, maybe just for debugging. You should remove it. In your case just simply print what you want to before, then print the result. If you want you can even create a function that (1) prints info about the operation and operands (2) calls the operator (3) prints the result. For example:

```
// Don't forget to remove cout statements from the overloaded +
void printThenAdd(Date dt0, Date dt1) {
    cout << "Addition: ";
    cout << dt0.mo << '/' << dt0.da << '/' << dt0.yr << " + ";
    cout << dt1.mo << '/' << dt1.da << '/' << dt1.yr;
    cout << " = " << dt0 + dt1 << endl;
}
```

Good luck! I can see how this would be confusing.